# PowerMock in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

Can you please help me to define the PowerMock for that code:

```
    String role = "ROLE_WARP_PUBLISH_PRIVATE";

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

    for (GrantedAuthority auth : authorities)
    {
        if(auth.getAuthority().equals(role))
        {
            if (publishCheckbox == true)
            {
                getScenarioService().makePublic(scenarioVersionId);
            }
        }

    }
```

So I know how that I have to mock the `getContext()` but I cannot return something when this method is called so I have a totally blackout how I can mock those few lines.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Normally with this type of question, you should try Google first. Stack Overflow is for fixing problems with code, not (and I don't mean to be offensive here) lack of knowledge. If you're going to as a question have a look at [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: @David Wilson I went trough Google and I know how it actually works but i coudn't implement it otherwise iI had done it so that's why I asked here.

Comment: Sadly I can't personally help you as I know nothing about java as it is - I was just reviewing the question.

Comment: That's what i found out so far:
Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
        SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);

        Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

Comment: @Herrminator never put more information into comments; update the question instead. And never ever put code into comments. Formatting matters.

Comment: I don't understand your question: why can't you return something when getContext() gets called? Please add what you tried, what the result was, and what result you like to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation: **forget** about using PowerMock.

If you have to mock static methods, then build your own little wrapper class around that. Then, for testing, your wrapper can return something **you** control; and for production usage; your wrapper just calls the static method.

PowerMock looks like the solution to many problems; but rather sooner than later, it will be the cause of **much more** problems.

Seriously: if your design can only be tested with PowerMock, this is very often a clear indication that your design is **bad**. So: focus on reworking your code under test; instead of investing time into a tool like PowerMock that does more harm than good.

I have spent countless hours trying to resolve PowerMock problems; and since instead started to write "better to test" production code ... I have written hundreds or thousands of tests without ever needing PowerMock again.

Comment: While I agree with the statement, I don't think it answers the question. I think this would be a great foot note on an actual answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough; I gave similar answers on similar questions more than once; and more important: more than once, the person accepted my answer in the end. Because, sometimes people realize that they are facing an XY problem; and that I gave them the answer to "Y" ... and that this information has much more value than getting the "X" answer.